# When inserting Twitter values to MYSQL database i get "Exeception occured:must be str" error

Tags: mysql, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to insert tweets into a mysql database.

I have the programme pulling the tweets, connecting and creating the database (If not created) sucessfully.

However, I get the error:

```
Exeception occurred: must be str, not int
```

When I run it i get this error. I am not sure how to find out which value it is referring to? Any ideas what is causing it?

I think it is that I have assigned the wrong datatype to the MYSQL column. So when I try and insert the int in to the str column it throws the error.

But i have been over it many times and this dosen't seem to be why...

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
from twitter_api import ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET


#import modules
from pymongo import MongoClient
import tweepy
import datetime
import pymysql.cursors


# Connect to Twitter API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


# Connect to MYSQL database
dbServerName = "localhost"
dbUser = "root"
dbPassword = "woodycool123"
dbName = "azure_support_tweets"
cusrorType = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor

connectionObject = pymysql.connect(host=dbServerName, user=dbUser, password=dbPassword, db=dbName, charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=cusrorType)


#Get 1000 tweets
searchQuery = "@azuresupport"
searched_tweets = []
last_id = -1
max_tweets = 1000

while len(searched_tweets) < max_tweets:
    count = max_tweets - len(searched_tweets)
    try:
        new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=100, max_id=str(last_id - 1))
        if not new_tweets:
            break
        searched_tweets.extend(new_tweets)
        last_id = new_tweets[-1].id
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        # depending on TweepError.code, one may want to retry or wait
        # to keep things simple, we will give up on an error
        break


# Create table for raw tweets if there is none
try:
    # Create a cursor object
    cursorObject = connectionObject.cursor()

    # SQL query string
    sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS raw_tweets(id_tweet int, id_str_status varchar(32), text_status varchar(200), created_at_status DATETIME(6), truncated varchar(32), in_reply_to_screen_name varchar(32), retweet_count int, favorite_count int, retweeted varchar(32), lang_status varchar(32), id_user int, id_str_user varchar(32), name_user varchar(32), screen_name varchar(32), location_user varchar(32), description_user varchar(32), url_user varchar(100), followers_count_user_user int, favourites_count_user int, lang_user varchar(32))"

    # Execute the sqlQuery
    cursorObject.execute(sqlQuery)


    # Add a row for each tweet
    for tweet in searched_tweets:
        if tweet.user.screen_name != "azuresupport":
            # Assign values to variables
            id_tweet = tweet.id
            id_str_status = str(tweet.id_str)
            text_status = tweet.text
            created_at_status = tweet.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            truncated = tweet.truncated
            in_reply_to_screen_name = tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name
            retweet_count = tweet.retweet_count
            favorite_count = tweet.favorite_count
            retweeted = tweet.retweeted
            lang_status = tweet.lang
            # Fields from the user object
            id_user = tweet.user.id
            id_str_user = tweet.user.id_str
            name_user = tweet.user.name
            screen_name_user = tweet.user.screen_name
            location_user = tweet.user.location
            description_user = tweet.user.description
            url_user = tweet.user.url
            followers_count_user_user = tweet.user.followers_count
            favourites_count_user = tweet.user.favourites_count
            lang_user = tweet.user.lang
            # Insert row
            values = " VALUES (" + id_tweet + id_str_status + text_status + created_at_status + truncated + in_reply_to_screen_name + retweet_count + favorite_count + retweeted + lang_status + id_user + id_str_user + name_user + screen_name + location_user + description_user + url_user, + followers_count_user_user + favourites_count_user + lang_user + ");"
            addrowQuery = "INSERT INTO raw_tweets (id_tweet, id_str_status, text_status, created_at_status, truncated, in_reply_to_screen_name, retweet_count, favorite_count, retweeted, lang_status), id_user, id_str_user, name_user, screen_name, location_user, description_user, url_user, followers_count_user_user, favourites_count_user, lang_user) " + values
            cursorObject.execute(addrowQuery)
            #commit
            connectionObject.commit()

except Exception as e:
    print("Exeception occured:{}".format(e))

finally:
    connectionObject.close()
```

Comment: can you share a sample data that you are trying to insert into the raw_tweets table? before the `# Insert row` that may give us a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I had been using the wrong datatypes.. python vs mysql database

I checked all the datatypes with type(i) and the mysql command DESCRIBE TABLE raw_tweets; And found were I had assigned the wrong datatype.

Thanks!